# Cómo pintar caracteres en lenguaje ensamblador z80 de 8x8

Tags: ensamblador

Pues eso, quiero saber como pintar un carácter en pantalla de 8*8 bits en lenguaje ensamblador para un procesador `z80`. Uso un emulador del `zx spectrum` llamado `zeus`.

Comment: Hola @jos3litros, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.